# iterate over file and send lines as positional parameters to another file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to iterate through a file containing dates (named dates.txt) in the following format:

```
2009 08 03 08 09
2009 08 03 09 10
2009 08 03 10 11
2009 08 03 11 12
2009 08 03 12 13
2009 08 03 13 14
```

And pass each field of each line as a positional parameter to another script.

ie: the other script is executed by putting the following at the command line:

```
$ . the_script 2009 08 03 08 09
```

I have tried `for i in $(./dates.txt);do echo ${i};done`

but get:

```
./dates: line 1: 2009: command not found
./dates: line 2: 2009: command not found
./dates: line 3: 2009: command not found
./dates: line 4: 2009: command not found
./dates: line 5: 2009: command not found
./dates: line 6: 2009: command not found
```

from this i can tell it is working through each line but perhaps getting hung up on each field?

Because of the above, I have yet been able to figure out how to pass the read lines as positional parameters to the other script. Not sure where to work it in either? Help, please!

Comment: Why are you using `. the_script` to run your script? This is called [sourcing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing) and should only be done when you explicitly want to make changes to the shell context, eg, change the current working directory, or to set functions or variables. Otherwise it "pollutes" your shell with any variables or functions that you define in the script, as well as (potentially) changing the current working directory. And if you call `exit` in a sourced script you'll exit the shell.

Comment: noted. it was more of a quick use. Please post solutions too and not merely problems. I am here to learn. i.e.: what SHOULD i use instead?

Comment: You should give `the_script` execute permissions and a [shebang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/preferred-bash-shebang) line so you can just run it directly. You can set file permissions in your GUI file manager, or you can do it on the commandline using the `chmod` command.

Comment: Note that I didn't say it is wrong to source your script, just that it may cause undesirable side-effects. You may have had very good reasons for sourcing it, but it was impossible to tell from the info in your question.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for the tips. Consider the file "shebanged" and it has been properly given permissions to execute (chmod +x).

Comment: So does Miroslav Franc's answer work for you? If so, you should accept it. If not, you may need to show us `the_script` so we can figure out why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
while read -d $'\n' i; do echo $i;done <./dates

while read -d $'\n' i; do . the_script $i;done <./dates
```

Comment: FWIW, `-d $'\n'` isn't strictly necessary, as `\n` is the default delimiter of `read`.

Comment: The less than symbol `<` is used to input a file as an argument. This works great `while read i; do ./the_script $i;done <./lstplanets`. What is the `.` for? I didn't use it and it works fine.

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum: My 1st comment on the question describes what the `.` does.

Comment: this worked great, thanks!                                     while read i; do ./avg_hr.sh $i; done <./dates

Comment: @PM2Ring Right, my bad.  For some reason I thought it was any white space.  I must have confused it with something else.  I usually use `read` with various separators to code split string function in a shell.

Comment: @MiroslavFranc: No worries. Explicitly specifying `-d` doesn't hurt, although some people might object that it makes the code verbose when it's not necessary.

Comment: Similarly, always specifying `-r` when using `read` is a Good Idea, even when it's unnecessary because you know the data won't contain backslashes (like in this case). Because if you leave it out when you do need it, then Bad Things happen. So it's a good habit to _always_ use `-r` so that you never forget about it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If sourcing (`.`) isn't needed, this sounds like a job for [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xargs.1):

```
xargs -a dates.txt -rL1 the_script
```

- `xargs` reads a line of input and then uses it for arguments for the command specified. The default line delimiter is the newline.
- We can pipe data to it from other commands, or specify an input file using `-a`.
- Since exactly one line is to be used per invocation of script, we specify the `-r` (don't run if line is empty) and `-L` (use at most N lines per invocation) options.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat` in your command and make sure you use the correct path to file name if the scripts are not in the same directory. If the list is `dates.txt` then use `$(cat ./dates.txt)`. **Edited typo here. Include the .txt**

Here is an example:

A list of dates named `dates.txt`.

```
2009 08 03 08 09
2009 08 03 09 10
2009 08 03 10 11
2009 08 03 11 12
2009 08 03 12 13
2009 08 03 13 14
```

A script named `lstdates.sh` to echo the planets in that list. **Edited**
This runs in a sub shell to that the internal field separator (IFS)[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) is not changed outside of the subshell[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752407/2407742).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Listing each date as an argument for `the_script`.

# Parenthesis runs in a subshell    
( 
  # IFS line break
  IFS=$'\012'
  for dates in $(cat ./dates.txt)
  do
    echo $(./the_script $dates)
  done
)
```

By default, IFS recognizes each whitespace as the end of a field. `IFS=$'\012'` recognizes each new line as the end of a field. If each line is wrapped in double quotes such as `"2009 08 03 08 09"`, then the default IFS will work.

`the_script` only contains the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

Reference: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide Chapter 11. Loops and Branches](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html)

Comment: This doesn't do what geokrowding wants. If you try your code using the data in the OP you'll see that it prints each number from the file on a separate line. In other words, each invocation of `echo` gets passed a single word of the file. BTW, `$(cat planets)` is preferred over the form using backticks, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 . Another reason not to use backticks is that it's not easy to display backticks in these comments. :)

Comment: Hey thanks, PM 2Ring. It now passes each line as and argument to the script called. Although, Miroslav's solution is way easier imo.

Comment: Are you sure? Try it on the OP data, and you'll see it still doesn't work right. Also, `echo $(some_command)` is weird.

Comment: Ah good eye. Updated and explanation added. It is only working if I keep the echo command. To test, I am passing it to `the_script` which only contains `echo $1`. This does seem weird and redundant tho.

Comment: This is pretty well explained here, although there are no examples for passing the output of each line as an argument for a script.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script